# Swift dictionary returns nil after setting key and value pair

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, struct, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a table view controller to section users based off of their occupation. I'm starting off with a dictionary and then converting it into a struct to display the different sections.

The dictionary takes a string and array of user objects:

```
var userByOccupation: [String: [User]] = [:]
```

I pull the occupations from the backend (firestore), then the user, then I append the user to the specified occupation. **However, whenever I set the value & key, then print out the value count from the dictionary, it's returning nil.**

Im getting the error in getUsers() function:

(see the last 3 lines that are also marked with their output)

```
func getOccupations(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("occupations").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if let error = err {
            print("There was an error fetching documents: \(error)")
        } else {
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            for document in documents {
                var occupationID = document.documentID
                db.collection("occupations").document(occupationID).collection("users").getDocuments(completion: { (secondSnapshot, error) in
                    if let err = error {
                        print("There was an error fetching documents: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        guard let secondDocuments = secondSnapshot?.documents else { return }
                        for document in secondDocuments {
                           self.getUsers(occupationID: occupationID, userID: document.documentID)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

func getUsers(occupationID: String, userID: String) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("users").document(userID).getDocument(completion: { (snapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
             print("There was an error fetching documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            if let dictionary = snapshot?.data() {
                let user = User(dictionary: dictionary  as [String: AnyObject])
                user.id = snapshot?.documentID
                print(occupationID) //MARK - prints: Janitor
                print(user.name) //MARK - prints: Jason
                self.userByOccupation[occupationID]?.append(user) //MARK: Setting the key & values
                print(self.userByOccupation.keys.count) //MARK - prints: nil.
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus What would that look like? I thought it was already non optional

Comment: My bad you have a dictionary you need to assign a default value when appending to a key `self.userByOccupation[occupationID, default: []]?.append(user)`

Comment: You should have asked yourself why there is a ? . It means you _expect_ that there might be no array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `?` with `self.userByOccupation[occupationID]` which is `nil` at first makes the statement affectless

```
self.userByOccupation[occupationID]?.append(user)
```

Change to

```
self.userByOccupation[occupationID] = [user] // or use +=
```